# How to write headers to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, csv-write-stream

I've wrote this code to write headers to a csv file:

```
    with open(os.path.join(directory, 'UserPass.csv'), 'wb') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames = ['Username', 'Password'], delimeter = ',')
    writer.writeheader()
```

However, it comes up with an error saying that directory is not defined.
Why is this happening, what would I define directory as?
Is there a better way to write headers?
Thank you.

Comment: The error is telling you that you did not assign anything to the `directory` variable before trying to use it.

Comment: `delimeter` is spelled wrong, but comma is the default anyway.

Comment: `with open('UserPass.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:` will open the file in your current directory (since you didn't define one) and `newline=''` is required for correct use with the `csv` module of Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Directory is the location of the directory (aka folder) that you want to save UserPass.csv. See [os.path.join docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way would be using `sed` since you mention alternatives, just do,

```
sed -i '1iUsername,Password' UserPass.csv
```

Comment: sorry, on which line?

Comment: from the command line, if you are not on Windows granted, can someone explain the downvote?